# How to pass type variable to a generic Svelte component?

Tags: typescript, firebase, svelte, sveltekit, pocketbase

I want to pass a type variable to a Svelte component so that its `<script>` can use the generic type `T` to fetch some data and pass it to a `<slot>`. I'm building a component that fetches data from a PocketBase database. For a component `MyComponent`, how can I pass a type variable `T`? In typical TypeScript, I'd expect something like `MyComponent<T>`.

The only approach I've come up with so far is to use a `seed` value of type `T` so that the component's other props are typed correctly. Here's an example:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import type { Record };

  type T = $$Generic<Record>;

  // Use a seed value to figure out T
  export let seed: T;

  // Take a record ID as input
  export let id: string;

  // Use that ID to fetch some data
  const data: T = fetchData<T>(id);
  
  // Share that data with the default slot
  interface $$Slots {
    default: { record: T };
  }
</script>

<slot record={data} />
```

```
<script lang="ts">
  import type { Record };

  interface SomeRecord extends Record{};

  const seed = {} as SomeRecord;
</script>

<MyComponent seed={seed} id="123abc" let:record>
  {record.id}
</MyComponent>
```

Is there a way to acomplish this without a `seed` prop?

Answer (score 1):

If the record type were an actual object, you could pass it in directly and possibly infer the type that way but for interfaces there currently is, to my knowledge, no other way of passing in that information.

I created a similar component before but made it take a promise as a property, which already would encode the result type, so you would get something like:

```html
<Loader promise={fetchUser(id)} let:value>
  ...
</Loader>
```

```js
// in loader
export let promise: Promise<T>;
```

Since your loading function is generic, it currently could not be used in the template directly, as that does not accept TS syntax ([issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4701)). You could extract that to the `<script>` if that works for you.